# React change individual button states on click

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript, react-hooks

I created a page that displays goods, next to every good there is a button with which you can select or deselect the good. My problem is, when I click on any of my buttons, all buttons change. How can I make it so that the callback function responsible for changing the state of the button only applies to the one that has been clicked?

```
import React from 'react';
import { useState } from 'react';
import 'bulma/css/bulma.css';
import './App.scss';

export const goods = [
  'Dumplings',
  'Carrot',
  'Eggs',
  'Ice cream',
  'Apple',
  'Bread',
  'Fish',
  'Honey',
  'Jam',
  'Garlic',
];

export const App: React.FC = () => {
  const [selected, selectGood] = useState(true);

  const [selectedGood, changeSelectedGood] = useState(goods[0])

  const handleChange = (button: any) => {
    changeSelectedGood(button.target.id);
    return selectGood(!selected);
  }

  const clearAll = () => {
    return selectGood(!selected);
  }

  return (
    <main className="section container">
    {!selected && (
      <h1 className="title">No goods selected</h1>
    )}

    {/* eslint-disable-next-line jsx-a11y/control-has-associated-label */}
    {selected && (
      <h1 className="title is-flex is-align-items-center">
        {selectedGood + ' is selected'}
        <button
        data-cy="ClearButton"
        type="button"
        className="delete ml-3"
        onClick={clearAll}
        />
      </h1>
      )}


    <table className="table">
      <tbody>

        {goods.map((good) => (
          <tr
            data-cy="Good"
            key={good}
            className={selected
              ? "has-background-success-light"
              : ""
            }
          >
          <td>
            {good && (
              <button
              data-cy="AddButton"
              type="button"
              className={"button"}
              id={good}
              onClick={(good) => {handleChange(good)}}
            >
              {selected ? '-' : '+'}
            </button>
            )}
          </td>

          <td
            data-cy="GoodTitle"
            className="is-vcentered"
          >
            {good}
          </td>
        </tr>
        ))}

        </tbody>
    </table>
  </main>
  )
}
```

Comment: In js we can use event.stopPropagation() and event.preventDefault()

Answer (score 1):

What you basically need is to have a state in which you can maintain the checked status and the value, on clicking the button, map over the status and update the status of element, that has been clicked by the user (in order to check which element user has clicked you either compare values or keep additional field such as id in the array). Below is a simpler(in sense of code) implementation of the same issue.

```
import * as React from 'react';
import './style.css';
import { useState } from 'react';

export default function App() {
  const [goods, setGoods] = useState([
    { status: false, name: 'Dumplings' },
    { status: false, name: 'carrot' },
  ]);
  const onClick = (event) => {
    setGoods(
      goods.map((item) => {
        if (item === event.target.name)
          return { ...item, status: !item.status };
        else return item;
      })
    );
  };
  return (
    <div>
      {goods.map((good, idx) => {
        return (
          <div key={idx}>
            <input
              value={good.name}
              type={'checkbox'}
              onClick={onClick}
              name={good.name}
            />
            <label htmlFor={good.name}> {good.name}</label>
          </div>
        );
      })}
    </div>
  );
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Why you don't do like this:

```
import { useState } from 'react'
import 'bulma/css/bulma.css'
import './App.scss'

export const goods = [ 'Dumplings', 'Carrot', 'Eggs', 'Ice cream', 'Apple', 'Bread', 'Fish', 'Honey', 'Jam', 'Garlic']

const App = () => {
  const [selectedGoods, setSelectedGoods] = useState<string[]>([])

  const clearAll = () => {
    return setSelectedGoods([])
  }

  const handleSelectGood = (good: string) => {
    setSelectedGoods(
      (selectedGoods: string[]) => selectedGoods.includes(good)
        ? selectedGoods.filter((selectedGood) => selectedGood !== good)
        : [...selectedGoods, good]
    )
  }

  return (
    <main className="section container">
      {/* header */}
      {selectedGoods.length < 1
        ? <h1 className="title">No goods selected</h1>
        : (
          <h1 className="title is-flex is-align-items-center">
            {selectedGoods.join(', ') + ' is selected'}
            <button
              onClick={clearAll}
              className="delete ml-3"
              type="button"
              data-cy="ClearButton"
            />
          </h1>
        )}
      {/* table */}
      <table className="table">
        <tbody>
          {goods.map((good) => {
            const isSelected = selectedGoods.includes(good)
            return (
              <tr
                key={good}
                className={isSelected ? "has-background-success-light" : ""}
                data-cy="Good"
              >
                <td>
                  <button
                    id={good}
                    onClick={() => handleSelectGood(good)}
                    className={"button"}
                    data-cy="AddButton"
                  >
                    {isSelected ? '-' : '+'}
                  </button>
                </td>
                <td
                  className="is-vcentered"
                  data-cy="GoodTitle"
                >
                  {good}
                </td>
              </tr>
            )
          })}
        </tbody>
      </table>
    </main>
  )
}

export default App
```

Comment: That works well, thank you, I think I need to make it so that I can only select one good at a time, I'll try refactoring it a little